# "SyntaxError: Unexpected token {": tsconfig not recognizing file within node_modules as valid typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor, tsconfig

I am referencing a simple function from a custom package in my node_modules folder and realized that it is attempting to read the file as javascript instead of typescript. What settings would I need to modify in my tsconfig.json in order for this to work properly?

I have tried wrapping the accessibilityCheck function inside a class and making it part of a module and exporting the module from the custom package for use in my test. Also tried swapping out the import statements for require statements.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2016"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc-e2e",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": ["../node_modules/e2e-utilities/*.ts"]
}
```

e2e-utilities is a custom package that we import to the current project

**node_modules/e2e-utilties/accessibility-check.ts**

```js
import { browser } from 'protractor';
import { AxeResults } from 'axe-core';
import { SarifLog, convertAxeToSarif } from 'axe-sarif-converter';
const util = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const axeBuilder = require('axe-webdriverjs');

export async function accessibilityCheck(
    fileName: string,
    selectorsToExclude?: string[],
    selectorsToInclude?: string[]): Promise<AxeResults> {
    const builder = axeBuilder(browser.driver);
    if (selectorsToInclude) {
        selectorsToInclude.forEach(selector => builder.include(selector));
    }
    if (selectorsToExclude) {
        selectorsToExclude.forEach(selector => builder.exclude(selector));
    }
    const axeResults: AxeResults = await builder.analyze();

    const sarifResults: SarifLog = convertAxeToSarif(axeResults);
    const a11yResultsFilepath = path.join(__dirname, '../..', 'accessibilityresults');
    if (!fs.existsSync(a11yResultsFilepath)) {
        await util.promisify(fs.mkdir)(a11yResultsFilepath);
    }
    const filepath = path.join(a11yResultsFilepath, fileName);
    await util.promisify(fs.writeFile)(filepath, JSON.stringify(sarifResults));
    return axeResults;
}
```

**test file**

```js
describe('Accessibility demo', () => {
    it('Running accessibility check on dashboard', async () => {
        const results = await accessibilityCheck('attract-dashboard.sarif', ['#talent-header'], []);
    });
});
```

**protractor.conf.js**

```
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');
const VideoReporter = require('protractor-video-reporter');
const Path = require('path');

exports.config = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
    useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
    specs: [
        Path.join('../../../../../', '/e2e/accessibility/**/*.a11y-spec.ts')
    ],
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            args: [
                '--start-maximized'
            ]
        }
    },
    chromeOnly: true,
    directConnect: true,
    baseUrl: 'https://localhost:443/',
    framework: 'jasmine',
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 110000,
        print: function () { }
    },
    beforeLaunch: function () {
        require('ts-node').register({
            project: 'e2e/tsconfig.json'
        });
    },
    onPrepare: function () {

        // Overrides default format of .mov to .avi to work in windows
        VideoReporter.prototype.jasmineStarted = function() {
            var self = this;
            if (self.options.singleVideo) {
                var videoPath = Path.join(self.options.baseDirectory, 'protractor-accessibility-specs.avi');
                self._startScreencast(videoPath);

                if (self.options.createSubtitles) {
                    self._subtitles = [];
                    self._jasmineStartTime = new Date();
                }
            }
        };

        console.log(process.env.DISPLAY)

        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
        var failFast = require('jasmine-fail-fast');
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(failFast.init());
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new VideoReporter({
            baseDirectory: Path.join(__dirname, 'a11y_report', Date.now().toString()),
            createSubtitles: true,
            singleVideo: true,
            ffmpegCmd: Path.normalize('C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe'),
            ffmpegArgs: [
                '-f', 'gdigrab',
                '-framerate', '30',
                '-i', 'desktop',
                '-q:v','5'
            ]
          }));
    }
};
```

```
e2e-utilities\accessibility-check.ts:7
import { browser } from 'protractor';
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

I instead expect this file to be parsed like a normal typescript file instead of a javascript file and failing.

Comment: node modules are generally supposed to be bundled in advance. can you just compile (or have the developer) compile the library in advance?

Comment: Yep, that did it.  I ran tsc on the accessibility-check.ts file to transpile it in the original packaged library and the error went away. If you submit your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node modules are generally supposed to be bundled in advance. when you get this type of error, ask the library developer to transpile in advance, and include declarations to keep the type safety.